# flutter How to call list of items inside SliverList

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Im very new to flutter, Im trying to do scrolling vertically and show horizontal cuisines and vertical restaurants list, for horizontal list it works fine but I don't know how to do this for the vertical list, please advice me with which is the best way to do it if I will have a huge number of restaurants in this list

```
SliverToBoxAdapter(//horizontal list
        child:  RestaurantsSlide(title: 'Featured Restaurants',),
      ),
      SliverList(
        delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
          [
           //How to call the list here

          ],
        ),
      ),
```

this is the function to return the list of restaurants

```
void restaurantCardList() {
List<dynamic> restaurantsList = RESTAURANT_DATA;
List<Widget> listItems = [];
restaurantsList.forEach((restaurant) {
  listItems.add(
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10, bottom: 25),
        child: RestaurantCard(restaurant: restaurant),
      )
  );
 }
);
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are using slivers? If you can get away with `ListView`s you should

Comment: Yes i want slivers because i want to scrolling vertically and horizontally as i have both in the page i tried listview but i think sliver is more better